# Grid Engine for program that needs X11 but doesn't require user input

Tags: bash, x11, gridengine

I have a bash script that calls an executable (some commercial software) in "batch mode". On the commandline, if X is available the program runs to completion and then quits, but if not the program hangs. 
I think this because:

- It works over VNC
- It doesn't work over ssh if `ssh -X` has not been specified.
- It works over ssh if -X has been specified
- It doesn't work with Grid Engine. When I qsub the script it just stays on status 'r' indefinitely and I cannot see any output in the .sh.o.XXX or .sh.e.XXX files

The upshot is, I want to submit this script to Grid Engine, but I can't!

The program never asks for user input when in the so-called "batch mode".

Is there some way to provide an X environment in Grid Engine, just to allow the program to complete on its own? 
I guess one problem is that, since I cannot see the source code, it is difficult to see exactly what the program is asking for.

Comment: you might be able to see where it is hanging if you run the binary with `strace` to see the system calls.

Answer (score 0):

You need [Xvfb](https://www.x.org/archive/X11R7.6/doc/man/man1/Xvfb.1.xhtml) which is a "headless" X display. Run it somewhere and in your script's env set $DISPLAY to that location.

Comment: Can you explain why Xvfb would work, but why setting the DISPLAY variable in my qsub script to some VNC server on the head node would not work?